# I get this syntax error when running my server.js trying to connect to my sql db

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I wrote this script to connect to my local DB with mssql and node.js.

Here is my "server.js" script:

```
const sql = require(‘mssql’);

//write the configuration to connect to our database:
var config = {

 user: ‘root’,

 password: ‘’,

 server: ‘localhost’,

 database: ‘testangular’

 };

sql.connect(config, function(err) {

 if (err) { console.log(‘Connect err: ‘ + err); return; }

 isConnected = true;

});
```

When I run it I get this syntax error:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIXwo.png)

I'm kind of new to javascript, so it might be a ridiculous mistake, but your help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Please don't provide info as screenshots, but insert it into the question. If the screenshot is deleted at some point, it will no longer be possible to understand the question.

Comment: Don't use a document editor like word to write code - it has a bad habit of replacing characters with "smarter" versions - like apostrophes, double quotes, line feeds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because You're using apostrophes. You should not use `‘` and `’` but `'` or `"`.

```js
const sql = require('mssql');

// write the configuration to connect to our database:
var config = {
 user: 'root',
 password: '',
 server: 'localhost',
 database: 'testangular'
};

sql.connect(config, function(err) {
 if (err) { console.log('Connect err: ', err); return; }
 isConnected = true;
});
```

**Tip**: I also suggest using semicolon here, in case `err` is an object.
`console.log('Connect err:', err);`